# Sum of random coin flips

Tags: probability, summation, random

Let `x` be a variable.
Lets say I have a coin and I flip it `n` times.
If it lands on tails, I add one to `x`.
Given a source of uniformly distributed numbers (0 to 1), how map it to a number between 0 and `n` so that the distribution of the random numbers is the same as the distribution of `x`? Also, please provide a more general way to do this for a biased coin, with probability of tails being `t`.

Comment: This is the problem of generating binomial random variates. There is a lot of literature out there about this for you to explore.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable $x$ is distributed according to the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n$ and $t$.

Take a look at the [generating binomial random variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Generating_binomial_random_variates) section to find how to transform a uniformly distributed random number to your variable $x$.